# Fire a specific SQL Query depending on the dropbox at the same page made using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

Well, I have a bootstrap Dropbox on this page and depending on the value selected I need to fire the SQL Query and only list down students of that particular batch.

**DropBox code:**

```
<tr>
    <td>
      <h5>'.$subject_name[$i].'</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
        0
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span id="'.$j.'" class="abc">Theory</span>
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu '.$j.'"" onclick="drop(event);">
          <li select value="theory"><a href="#">Theory</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li value="Practical A"><a href="#">Practical - A</a></li>
          <li value="Practical B"><a href="#">Practical - B</a></li>
          <li value="Practical C"><a href="#">Practical - C</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li value="Elective PCD"><a href="#">Electives - PCD</a></li>
          <li value="Elective OR"><a href="#">Electives - OR</a></li>
          <li value="Elective HCI"><a href="#">Electives - HCI</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        <script>
            $(".'.$j.' a").click(function(){
             $("#'.$j.'").text($(this).text());
             });
        </script>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
              Mark attendance
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$v= $_GET['link2'];
switch () {
  case 'Practical - A':
     $v=1;          
     $sql1="select * from student where batch_code = ".$v;
     echo $sql1;
    break;
    case 'Practical - B':
      # code...
    $v=2;
    $sql1="select * from student where batch_code = ".$v;
    echo $sql1;
    break;
    case 'Practical - C':
      # code...
    $v=3;
    $sql1="select * from student where batch_code = ".$v;
    echo $sql1;
    break;
    default:
    $sql1="select * from student";
    break;
}
echo $sql1;
$result=mysql_query($sql1);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
$student_name[]=Array();
for ($i=0; $i <$num ; $i++) { 
    # code...
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $student_name[$i]=$row["student_name"];
        $student_rollno[$i]=$row["student_rollno"];
        echo ' <tr>
<td>'.$student_rollno[$i].'</td>
<td>'.$student_name[$i].'</td>
<td>
      <input class="checkbox" name="mark" type="checkbox" value="1">
</td>
</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Research AJAX - it's probably the easiest way to implement what you want.

Comment: Make a ajax call by passing you parameters. See JQuery AJAX